# Kill Process Razer Synapse in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, console-application

I wanna kill process in C# but i am getting error.

Code:

```
Process[] processes2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("RzSynapse.exe");
foreach (var process in processes2)
{
process.Kill();
}
```

I am trying to kill Razer Synapse

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: OK i just solve that thx for help